# Boolean on object data type in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, object, numpy, pandas

I'm importing a csv file to a data frame. I then want to eliminate any records that contain a particular string in one of the series. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
print df.head(3)
```

gives

```
    identity    quantity      fruit
0          1           3     apples
1          2           4    oranges
2          3           8     apples
```

I then want to remove any records containing apples. My attempts have been centred around variations on the expression

```
df = df[df.fruit != 'apples']
```

however this throws the error

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

When checking the data types, I can see that the fruit series is actually stored as an object type, which apparently cannot be directly compared with a string

```
df.dtypes

id                       int64
identity               float64
quantity               float64
fruit                   object
```

I've tried several ways around the issue including importing the data as

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype={'fruit':str})
```

which removes the error message but doesn't actually have any effect on removing the records that I want to get rid of when I use the boolean expression.

Are there any solutions or workarounds for this?

**EDIT**

Checking the type gives

```
type(df.fruit)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

and printing the dataframe as a dictionary

```
print df.to_dict()
{'identity': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0}, 'quantity': {0: 3.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 8.0}, 
'fruit': {0: 'apples', 1: 'oranges', 2: 'apples'}}
```

Using the alternative expression

```
df = df[df['fruit'] != 'apples']
```

also raises the type comparison error, whereas

```
df[df.fruit.astype('str') != 'apples']
```

raises no error, but also does not remove the desired records.

I have actually found a solution. If I write a function that can be called with a parameter "remove"

```
def CleanFruit(df, remove=None):
    df = df[df.fruit != remove]
    return df

df = CleanFruit(df, remove='apples')
```

This yields the desired result but I don't know why it works.

Comment: can you run `print df.to_dict()` copy and paste it into your question at the bottom?  Thx.

Comment: Can you check `type(df.fruit)` and also can you change the line with `df = df[df['fruit'] != 'apples']`. My guess is that `df.fruit` is not a column but something else.

Comment: Is there any difference when you try `df[df.fruit.astype('str') != 'apples']`?

Comment: are you sure that you are not comparing datetime-like column with a numeric-like column (i mean your real data set)? I could find this error message only in the `pandas/core/ops.py` method:  `_comp_method_SERIES()`

Comment: Thanks all. @piRsquared, I have put that in the edit. There is also a solution that I found.

Comment: @ƘɌỈSƬƠƑ;@maxcalibur: somehow the "astype(str)" solution worked. But I don't understand why. The program is not broken, it works on other data, it just seems to fail on some dataset I have and I want to understand why.